# Intersection of circle and geodesic segment on sphere

Tags: algorithms, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am trying to find an efficient way of computing the intersection point(s) of a circle and line segment on a spherical surface.

Say you have a sphere of radius R. On the surface of this sphere are

1. a circle with center ($\theta_c$,$\phi_c$) and radius r
2. a geodesic line segment defined by endpoints ($\theta_1$,$\phi_1$) and ($\theta_2$,$\phi_2$)

where $\theta$ is the colatitude in $[0,\pi]$, $\phi$ is the longitude in $[0,2\pi]$, and $r$ is measured by the geodesic distance on the sphere (not straight line distance in Euclidean space). How would you

1. determine whether the circle and line intersect at all, including whether the segment is contained by the circle?
2. compute the intersection point(s)?

We can assume there is nothing pathological going on. $r$ is not zero and is not so large that it's bigger than the sphere, the line's endpoints are not identical, etc.

Comment: How about stereographic projection? It maps circles to circles so you're left with elementary geometry

Comment: Given two end points there are two (geodesic) line segments that have those end points. How do you define which one you have?

Comment: Arthur - I'm taking the path from $P_1$ to $P_2$ in the direction of $P_2-P_1$. There is the pathological case where they are $\pi$ degrees opposite each other.

Comment: @arthur So you take it to mean the shorter of the two segments (barring the antipodal pathology, of course, but that's not $\pi$ degrees). That's fine. But I care more about what qsfzy takes it to mean, as they are the one who actually has the answer.

Comment: It would be fair to take the smaller of the two possible geodesics. An acceptable definition can be "the path from $P_1$ to $P_2$ in the direction of $P_2 - P_1$".

Answer (score 2):

If everything is converted from geographic coordinates to Cartesian vectors, the calculation can be done by linear algebra and trigonometry.

Let $P_{0}$ denote the center of the circle $C$; $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ the endpoints of the geodesic segment; and assume

- $P_{1} \neq \pm P_{2}$, so there is a unique short arc of great circle from $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$;
- $r < \pi R/2$, so $C$ is not a great circle.

[image: A geodesic arc intersecting a circle on a sphere]

The great circle through $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ is the intersection of the sphere with the plane $\Pi$ containing $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$, and the origin (the center of the sphere), which has unit normal vector
$$
N = \frac{P_{1} \times P_{2}}{\|P_{1} \times P_{2}\|}.
$$
The angle subtended at the center of the sphere by the center of $C$ and a point of $C$ is $\theta = r/R$. Further, $\Pi$ intersects $C$ if and only if $N$ makes angle no larger than $\theta$ with the "equator" perpendicular to $P_{0}$, if and only if
$$
\biggl|\frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos \frac{P_{0} \cdot N}{R}\biggr|
= \biggl|\arcsin \frac{P_{0} \cdot N}{R}\biggr| \leq \theta.
$$
If this inequality fails to hold, the plane $\Pi$ (and hence the geodesic segment) does not intersect $C$. If equality holds, $C$ is tangent to $\Pi$, and if strict inequality holds $C$ crosses $\Pi$.

Suppose the preceding inequality is satisfied. The Euclidean center of $C$ is $c_{0} = (\cos\theta)P_{0}$.

Let $P_{2}'$ denote the vector on the short arc starting at $P_{1}$ and heading toward $P_{2}$ that is perpendicular to $P_{1}$; namely, scale the orthogonal projection
$$
P_{2} - \frac{P_{1} \cdot P_{2}}{R^{2}} P_{1}
$$
to have magnitude $R$. Points on the great circle have the form
$$
Q = (\cos t)P_{1} + (\sin t)P_{2}'
$$
for some real $t$. Such a point lies on $C$ if and only if $(Q - c_{0}) \cdot P_{0} = 0$, or
$$
(\cos t)P_{1} \cdot P_{0} + (\sin t)P_{2}' \cdot P_{0} = c_{0} \cdot P_{0} = R^{2}\cos\theta.
$$
If we set
$$
A = P_{1} \cdot P_{0},\qquad
B = P_{2}' \cdot P_{0},\qquad
C = R^{2}\cos \theta,
$$
this equation is written $A\cos t + B\sin t = C$. To solve, let $t_{0} = \operatorname{atan2}(B, A)$ be the unique angle in $[0, 2\pi)$ satisfying
$$
\cos t_{0} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^{2} + B^{2}}},\qquad
\sin t_{0} = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^{2} + B^{2}}}.
$$
By the addition formula for cosine, we have
$$
\cos(t - t_{0}) = \frac{R^{2}\cos\theta}{\sqrt{(P_{1} \cdot P_{0})^{2} + (P_{2}' \cdot P_{0})^{2}}},
$$
which yields
$$
t = t_{0} \pm \arccos\frac{R^{2}\cos\theta}{\sqrt{(P_{1} \cdot P_{0})^{2} + (P_{2}' \cdot P_{0})^{2}}}.
$$
This gives two points on the great circle that lie on $C$.

It remains to check whether either point lies on the short arc of great circle from $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$. But $Q = (\cos t)P_{1} + (\sin t)P_{2}'$ lies on the arc of great circle from $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$ if and only if $0 \leq t \leq \arccos(P_{1} \cdot P_{2}/R^{2})$. Alternatively, a point $Q$ of the great circle lies between $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ (i.e., on the short arc) if and on if the angle from $P_{1}$ to $Q$ plus the angle from $Q$ to $P_{2}$ equals the angle from $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$, i.e.,
$$
\arccos \frac{P_{1} \cdot Q}{R^{2}} + \arccos \frac{P_{2} \cdot Q}{R^{2}} = \arccos \frac{P_{1} \cdot P_{2}}{R^{2}}.
$$
(In the diagram, these were checked numerically and colored accordingly, green if *yes* and red if *no*.)

Comment: I'm going to implement this but, based on what I've already done, it seems correct. One note, we can use $\arcsin$ instead of $\pi/2 - \arccos$ in the second equation.

Comment: I'm following and everything is working until I get to $t_0$. @andrew-d-hwang, you say "let $t_0$ be the unique angle..." satisfying those two equations. Are we required to find $t_0$ numerically?

Comment: Yes, but (1) many libraries (C, JavaScript, ...) have an `atan2` function for which `atan2(y, x)` [sic] returns $\theta$; (2) If such a function is unavailable, we can find the two values of $t$ satisfying $\cos t = A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and the two values satisfying $\sin t = B/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and set $t_{0}$ to be the common value.

Comment: In case it matters for posterity, the diagram shows a unit sphere; in general, all the labeled points and vectors except $N$ have magnitude $R$, and therefore lie on the sphere, while $N$ is a unit vector.

Answer (score 0):

The edge of the circle is on a plane that cuts the sphere normal to the radius, call it the cplane.

The line segment is on a circle disk that passes through the two points on the sphere and passes through the origin. This circle is on a plane, call it the lplane.

The circle and line segment are on the sphere.

The strategy is to find the equations of the planes and solve them along with the sphere equation.

If real solutions exist then check that they are on the line segment.

Three points are required to determine the equation of a plane.

$$(R-R_0) \cdot N = 0 \tag{1}$$
$R = (x,y,z)$.$R_0$ is a fixed point on the plane. $N$ is the normal to the plane. Three points are required to find the normal.

**cplane**

The center point $(R,\theta_c,\phi_c)$ is **not** on the cplane.

---

**Edit $1$ start:**

The normal to the cplane is the vector from the origin $\mathbf{O}$ to the center of the circle, $N_c = (R,\theta_c,\phi_c)$.

$C_1 = \left(R,\theta_c +\frac{r}{R},\phi_c\right)$ and $C_2 = \left(R,\theta_c -\frac{r}{R},\phi_c\right)$ are two points on the circle radius $r$.

Convert $N_c$ and $C_1$ into Cartesian coordinates. Take $N_c$ and $R_0 = C_1$ plug them into $(1)$ this will give the equation of the cplane of the form:

**Edit $1$ end:**

---

$$ax + by + cz = d \tag{2}$$

**lplane**

The origin $\mathbf{O}$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are three points that determine the lplane.

Convert $\mathbf{O}$,$P_1$ and $P_2$ into Cartesian coordinates.

Take $N_l = P_1 \times P_2$, $R_0 = \mathbf{O}$ plug them into $(1)$. This will give an equation of the form:

$$ex + fy + gz = 0 \tag{3}$$

**The Sphere**

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2 \tag{4}$$

**Solution**

Solve equations $(2),(3),(4)$. It forms a quadratic in one variable.

If the solutions are complex then there is no solution, (complex conjugates).

If there is one real solution or a real double root then the lplane touches the cplane on the sphere at one point.

If there are two real solutions then the lplane cuts the cplane on the sphere at two points.

The **line segment** $P_1P_2$ is only part of the lplane.

**Are the solutions inside the line segment $P_1P_2$?**

Take the path from $P_1$ to $P_2$ in the direction of $P_2-P_1$. There is the pathological case where they are $\pi$ degrees opposite each other.

It requires a parameterized equation of the path.

Let $\widehat{V}$ denote the unit vector in the direction of $V$.

Find the unit vector $\widehat{Q}$ in the lplane normal to $\widehat{P_1}$.

$\widehat{Q} = \widehat{(\widehat{P_2}-(\widehat{P_2}  \cdot \widehat{P_1})\widehat{P_1})} \tag{5}$

The $P_1$ $P_2$ path can be parameterized as:

$$P = \widehat{P_1}R\cos(\alpha) + \widehat{Q}R\sin(\alpha) \tag{6}$$

At $\alpha_1 = 0$ then $P = \widehat{P_1}R = P_1$.

At $\alpha_2$ let $P_2 = \widehat{P_1}R\cos(\alpha_2) + \widehat{Q}R\sin(\alpha_2)$.

Solve for $\alpha_2$ in the positive sense $[0,2\pi)$.

At the solution $S(S_x,S_y,S_z)$

$$S = \widehat{P_1}R\cos(\alpha_s) + \widehat{Q}R\sin(\alpha_s) \tag{7}$$

Solve for $\alpha_s$ in the positive sense $[0,2\pi)$.

If $0 \le \alpha_s \le \alpha_2$ then the solution is on the line segment.

**Is the line segment inside the circle?**

There must be two real solutions for the line segment to be inside the circle.

Parameterize the circular arc starting from solution $1$ $S_1$ to solution $2$ $S_2$. Determine the angle of $S_2$ relative to $S_1$. Determine the angle of the points $P_1$ and $P_2$ wrt $S_1$. If the angles of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are less than the angle of $S_2$ then they are inside the curve. Note the arc from $S_1$ to $S_2$ is the same curve as from $P_1$ to $P_2$ but the angle starts at $S_1$. The direction from $S_1$ to $S_2$ is key.This method avoids complicated $2\pi - angle$ shortest angle scenarios that I could not resolve.

Let $\widehat{T}$ be normal to $\widehat{S_1}$ in the $\mathbf{O}S_1S_2$ plane.

$$\widehat{T} = \widehat{ \widehat{S_2} - (\widehat{S_2}\cdot \widehat{S_1}) \widehat{S_1} } \tag{8} $$

$$SPath = \widehat{S_1}R\cos(\beta) + \widehat{T} R \sin(\beta) \tag{9}$$

Solve $\beta$ for $S_2$,$P_1$ and $P_2$ on the SPath in a positive sense $[0,2\pi)$.

$$S_2 = \widehat{S_1}R\cos(\beta_{S2}) + \widehat{T} R\sin(\beta_{S2}) \tag{10}$$
$$P_1 = \widehat{S_1}R\cos(\beta_1) + \widehat{T} R\sin(\beta_1) \tag{11}$$
$$P_2 = \widehat{S_1}R\cos(\beta_2) + \widehat{T} R\sin(\beta_2) \tag{12}$$

If $0 \le \beta_1,\beta_2 \le \beta_{S2}$ then the line segment is inside the circle.

Comment: Seems like a promising start, but I think your definition of the **cplane** is only correct for a circle at the equator, $\theta = \pi/2$. For example, think about a circle that is centered on the "north pole", $(R,0,0)$. The four points $C_{[1,2,3,4]}$ you define for the cplane would be $(R, r/R, 0)$, $(R, -r/R, 0)$, $(R, 0, r/R)$, and $(R, 0, -r/R)$. The last two points are indistinguishable from each other and also from the crater's center at the pole because all three have $\theta = 0$. More generally, I think this definition is also wrong for $\theta \in [0,\pi/2)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: The rough steps of my current solution are:
**1)** rotate the circle to the pole so that it is defined by a ring at $\theta_c$ (rotating the segment also, of course)
**2)** parametrize the great circle running through the rotated segment
**3)** solve for parameter values where this great circle meets $\theta_c$
**4)** check if the intersection values overlap the segment

Comment: qfsy - The equations for $C_{[1,2,3,4]}$ are incorrect. The radius in the $xy$ plane is $R_{xy} = R \sin(\theta)$, not $R$. I'll try to patch this up.